# ElasticSearch.NET - Indexing parent / child nodes in different indexes

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest, elastic-stack

I am trying to follow this tutorial on creating parent-child relationships between items;

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/master/parent-child-relationships.html

My use-case is slightly different because the tutorial is creating a parent/child relationship between items in the same index, of the same type. I want to create one between two different types of object, which need to be stored in different indexes. I came up with something like this;

```
class MyParentType
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Data {get;set;}
    public JoinField MyJoinField { get; } = typeof(MyParentType);
}

class MyChildType
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Data {get;set;}
    public JoinField ParentJoinField { get; set; }

    public MyChildType(MyParentType parent)
    {
        ParentJoinField = JoinField.Link<MyChildType, MyParentType>(parent);
    }
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(
            pool, (builtin, settings) => new JsonNetSerializer(builtin, settings,
                () => new JsonSerializerSettings { Converters = { new StringEnumConverter() } }))
        .DefaultMappingFor<MyParentType>(m => m.IndexName("parents_index"))
        .DefaultMappingFor<MyChildType>(m => m.IndexName("children_index").RelationName("parents"));

    var client = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);

    client.CreateIndex("parents_index", c => c
        .Index<MyParentType>()
        .Mappings(m => m.Map<MyParentType>(n => n
            .RoutingField(r => r.Required())
            .AutoMap<MyParentType>())));

    client.CreateIndex("children_index", c => c
        .Mappings(m => m.Map<MyChildType>(n => n
            .RoutingField(r => r.Required())
            .AutoMap<MyChildType>()
            .Properties(props => props
                .Join(j => j
                    .Name(l => l.ParentNoteJoinField)
                    .Relations(r => r
                        .Join<MyParentType, MyChildType>()))))));

    var descriptor = new BulkDescriptor();
    descriptor.IndexMany(GetSomeCollectionOfParents());
    var response = client.Bulk(descriptor);
}
```

However, the last line returns a failed response from ElasticSearch;

> operation[0]: index returned 400 _index: parents_index _type: myparenttype _id: 123 _version: 0 error: Type: mapper_parsing_exception Reason: "object mapping for [myJoinField] tried to parse field [myJoinField] as object, but found a concrete value"

Could someone please point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The Parent/Child relationship in Elasticsearch mandates that Parent and Child documents reside in the same index; in fact, Child documents reside in the same shard as the Parent document. You can always index documents in one index with field values of the ids of documents in another index, but this can't use Parent/Child relationships, the `join` field, or any of the Parent/Child queries

Comment: Thank you @RussCam, I keep trying to treat Elasticsearch like a relational database; i.e. the types in one index are contiguous and relate to other types in other indexes. I need to get out of that mindset.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I do not need any `JoinField` on my parent object. It should be more like this;

```cs
class MyParentType
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Data {get;set;}
}
```

And the indexing;

```cs
client.CreateIndex("parents_index", c => c
    .Index<MyParentType>()
    .Mappings(m => m.Map<MyParentType>(n => n
        .AutoMap<MyParentType>())));

client.CreateIndex("children_index", c => c
    .Index<MyChildType>()
    .Mappings(m => m.Map<MyChildType>(n => n
        .RoutingField(r => r.Required())
        .AutoMap<MyChildType>()
        .Properties(props => props
            .Join(j => j
                .Name(l => l.ParentNoteJoinField)
                .Relations(r => r
                    .Join<MyParentType, MyChildType>()))))));
```

This seems to work, and I get an indexed child object similar to this;

```json
{
  "_source": {
    "id": "1",
    "parentJoinField": {
      "name": "parents",
      "parent": "123"
    },
  }
}
```